# Global Error Handling in WCF - but returning custom message

Tags: wcf, error-handling

I want to provide global error handling in my WCF application, and I know that I can implement my IErrorHandler, for example:

```
http://www.remondo.net/wcf-global-exception-handling-attribute-and-ierrorhandler/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26320/WCF-Error-Handling-and-Fault-Conversion
http://www.haveyougotwoods.ca/2009/06/24/creating-a-global-error-handler-in-wcf
```

However, what I'd really like to do is "handle" the exception, not just by logging or throwing a Fault exception, but by passing back a custom message back to the caller. We already use a custom message for returning back business-related messages (like validation errors or warnings).

In very rough pseudo code, I would do this in a try-catch block like this

```
public MyResponseDto CallMyService(MyRequestDto request)
{
        ... 
        try
            responseDto = blah blah blah
        catch (Exception ex)
            responseDto.ClientMessage.Description = ex.Messaeg
        finally    
           return responseDto;
}
```

My question is - how can I do this in my global handler? How will it get access to "ClientMessage"?

My gut feeling is that I would need to use Attributes and then reflection to get access to my Service internal members??? but how do I assign it back to my response message object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just a year late or so, but for people who might find your questions...

The signature of the ProvideFault method in the IErrorHandler interface looks like this:

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
```

The last parameter is what you are looking for. The Message class has a static method CreateMessage() with a lot of overloads. We are using it this way:

```
fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, "", new CustomErrorMessageDto("some error message"), new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(CustomErrorMessageDto)));
```

This allows us to provide the client with a custom DTO that's serialized to Json. (Note that we are returning a Stream object from our service in order to be able to return a custom format like Json.)